# Matched vs. Matching

Tags: word-choice

Which sentence is correct or more natural

- If it matches any of the items, **the item** is selected
- If it matches any of the items, **the matching item** is selected
- If it matches any of the items, **the matched item** is selected
- If it matches any of the items, **the item which is matched** is selected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, matched doesn't make sense in your examples: This would be used if the items were *already paired/sorted*:

> After the selecting process, the matched items are displayed.

The other two depend on context:

> **A.** If it matches any of the items, the item is selected.

Take an item X. Compare it to a set of items. If in the set is another item X', choose X, else discard X.

> **B.** If it matches any of the items, the matching item is selected.

Take an item X. Compare it to a set of items. If in the set is another item X', pick X', else ignore X'.

Real world example: You go shopping with your child.
**A.** Your child brings you a can of pineapples. If canned pineapple is on your shopping list, put it in the cart, else put the can back on the shelf.
**B.** Your shopping list has canned pineapple on it. You go to the shelf with canned fruit. If there is a can of pineapple, put it in your cart, ignoring the canned peaches.

Comment: Then matched points to something that already paired, but matching is something that is under process?

Comment: @Ahmad Yup. Matched is when it is paired (*past* participle, if used as adjective it also means "already paired"), matching is current (adjective).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is:
if matching is adjective, the subject involves multiple parties. So the sentence could be 
If it matches any of the items,  matching items(including "it" and others) are selected.

Comment: Guesses aren't what we're looking for. Please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and read about [good anwers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).